# How to set de spacing between the text and the image caption to `\baselineskip`?

Tags: spacing, graphics

I tried to set everything to `\baselineskip` in the code below, but the space between the text and the image not match with the rest of the text.

```latex
\documentclass[14paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,caption,csquotes,setspace}

\makeatletter
\setstretch{1.5}
\setlength{\intextsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\floatsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\jot}{\baselineskip}

\renewcommand\section{
  \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}
  {-\baselineskip}
  {\baselineskip}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{ALSDJKFH  ALSKDJFH}
ALSDJKFH  ALSKDJFH LASKJDHF ALSKDJFHALSDKJFHA SLDKJFHALSKDJFHALSKDJFH ALSKDJF ALKSJDHF ALSJDKFHALKJSD FLAKJSD FLKJAHSDF LKJAHSD FLJKAHSDF LKJAHSD FLKJAHSD FLKJAHSDFLKJAHSD LFKJHKLAJSDHFLAKJ SDHFL AKSJDHF LAKJSDHF ALKDJSFH 
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
        \caption*{ALSDJKFH  ALSKDJFH}
        \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption*{ALSDJKFH  ALSKDJFH}
\end{figure}
ALSDJKFH  ALSKDJFH LASKJDHF ALSKDJFHALSDKJFHA SLDKJFHALSKDJFHALSKDJFH ALSKDJF ALKSJDHF ALSJDKFHALKJSD FLAKJSD FLKJAHSDF LKJAHSD FLJKAHSDF LKJAHSD FLKJAHSD FLKJAHSDFLKJAHSD LFKJHKLAJSDHFLAKJ SDHFL AKSJDHF LAKJSDHF ALKDJSFH 
\end{document}
```

In the image below, all green rectangles have the same height. But the spacing on top of the image caption is smaller than one `\baselineskip` (yellow rectangle) and the space below is larger than `\baselineskip` (red rectangle). But to my university template, everything should be with the same spacing. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Oh, dear. Have you tried asking around to see if anyone has a class designed to satisfy the university requirements? If you're not in maths, try asking in maths. I ask because systematically preventing LaTeX from trying to produce a good result is not straightforward and, if your uni has this kind of (typographically bonkers) requirement, they are all too likely to have others.

Comment: The way Latex works is similar to how typesetters did with letters made from lead: form blocks, move them around, fill spaces, try obtaining a pleasing appearance. // Which means: you must give Latex something to move around while trying to optimize, which is done here by using a float environment for the figure. // So if you really want to mimick MS-Word, try adjusting the size of your image, until it fits (and don't change your text thereafter ;-) Or, which I suggest to do, adopt the Latex way of presenting content.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This is only a partial answer, as some spacing is still wrong. Putting this as an answer because it's a bit long and I can't comment.

First, the block you draw is larger than a `\baselineskip`. A `\baselineskip` is the length between two baselines.
Therefore, the spacing after the section title seems to be larger than `\baselineskip`. I will suggest looking into the `\titlespacing` command from the `titlesec` package.

Secondly, the `caption` package guesses the relative position of the caption and the image to add the correct spacing. In this case, it thinks the caption appears above the image, hence the second caption is spaced incorrectly. This will not happen if the top caption is removed. (That is, the provided example actually creates a false scenario by adding two captions to a single figure.)

Finally, when using the packages `caption` and `setspace` together, you need to set the font stretch for the caption separately (as done in `font=stretch={1.5}` below.)
Please refer to the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) of the `caption` package for more info.

Below is a partially fixed version and its output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font={stretch=1.5}]{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\makeatletter
\setstretch{1.5}
\setlength{\intextsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\floatsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\jot}{\baselineskip}

\renewcommand\section{
  \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}
  {-\baselineskip}
  {\baselineskip}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{ALSDJKFH  ALSKDJFH}
ALSDJKFH ALSKDJFH LASKJDHF ALSKDJFHALSDKJFHA SLDKJFHALSKDJFHALSKDJFH ALSKDJF ALKSJDHF ALSJDKFHALKJSD FLAKJSD FLKJ
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
        \caption*{ALSDJKFH  ALSKDJFH}
        \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}
        % \caption*{ALSDJKFH  ALSKDJFH}
\end{figure}
ALSDJKFH ALSKDJFH LASKJDHF ALSKDJFHALSDKJFHA SLDKJFHALSKDJFHALSKDJFH ALSKDJF ALKSJDHF ALSJDKFHALKJSD FLKJHKL
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
        % \caption*{ALSDJKFH  ALSKDJFH}
        \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption*{ALSDJKFH  ALSKDJFH}
\end{figure}
ALSDJKFH ALSKDJFH LASKJDHF ALSKDJFHALSDKJFHA SLDKJFHALSKDJFHALSKDJFH ALSKDJF ALKSJDHF ALSJDKFHALKJSD FLAKJSD FLKJ
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Hope this gets you one step closer to the desired output.